# React Native yarn run ios/android or npm run ios/android not working (Could not get status from Metro bundler)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, metro-bundler

I've been coding a React Native application by running the app on my android device by doing: `yarn start`

My app has been ejected from expo but I'm still using expo for development and on a android device and with yarn start it works ok....my problem now is running it on a simulator on my MacBook Pro...

I currently do not have my own ios device and therefore would need to run via the simulator on my MacBook Pro.  I try to run the react native app via the simulator via: `yarn run ios`

However when I run that the simulator does not start and I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ expo start --ios
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                         │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.18.4).                │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.17.10                              │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Starting project at /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactNative/EjectedExpo/JyotishEject
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I then tried the android version by running: `yarn run android` and I get the same error....

how to fix this?

I would like to start working on the ios version asap thru the simulator....

I have now tried running: expo start -c --ios

and I get the following error:

```
Error running `xcrun simctl openurl booted myapp://127.0.0.1:19000`: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code=-10814):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Error running app. Have you installed the app already using Xcode? Since you are detached you must build manually. Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 194
Your native app is running at myapp://192.168.100.189:19000
```

Comment: Looks like there is some issue with the metro bundler availability. try to kill the already running metro bundler or clear the cache using `yarn start --reset-cache` and try running once

Answer (score 1):

Step - 1 :
Try installing node.js from its [official website](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.14.2/node-v18.14.2-x64.msi)

Step - 2 : Install yarn using **npm install --global yarn** command in the command line.

Step - 3 : Install **Android Studio** and **create device** under Virtual Device Manager Section and then click on play button to open the emulator.
[image]

Step - 3 : switch on the emulator(virtual device) by clicking on the **power button** on the upper right corner.

Step - 4 : run **yarn android** in vs code terminal in the **current directory** to see the progress of the app.